# How do I calculate $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as

$ f(x)  = \begin{cases} 1,\text{if} \  x=\frac{1}{n} ,n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\} \text   {otherwise}  \end{cases}$.

Calculate $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$.

My attempt:

Let  $f_1 = 1 , f_2 =0$ , now  $f = f_1 +f_2$

$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx =\int_{0}^{1} f_1(x)dx  +\int_{0}^{1} f_2(x)dx  =1$

I don't  know  whether I'm right or wrong. It just came to my mind.

Please verify.

Comment: Why do you claim that $f_1+f_2=f$?

Comment: $$\int_{[0,1]} f = \int_{\{1/n\}} f + \int_{[0,1]\setminus\{1/n\}} f = \int_{\{1/n\}} f + \int_{[0,1]\setminus\{1/n\}} 0 = \int_{\{1/n\}} f. $$  Since the set $\{1/n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a nullset, the last integral is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$0\leq\int\limits_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \int\limits_0^{1/n}f(x)\,dx+\int\limits_{1/n}^1f(x)\,dx = \int\limits_0^{1/n}f(x)\,dx \leq1/n $$
Because Riemann integral doesn't change when the function being integrable changes by finite amount of points (for this reason $\int_{1/n}^1 f(x)\,dx = 0$). Taking $n\to \infty$ we see that the limit is $0$.

Another approach is to just use Lebesgue integration, but that's more advanced and probably not on your level of education yet.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N=\{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb N\}$ and $g(x)=1$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Then we have: $N$ is a null-set and that $f=g$ a.e.

Hence

$$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1} g(x)dx=1.$$

Comment: Surely you want $g(x) = 0$, and so the integral is $0$.

Comment: Given the question, I doubt the OP understands null sets.